# Передать метод как аргумент

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Operarray {
    public static void f() {
        System.out.println("123");
    }

    private static void func(Operarray f1) {
        f1();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func(Operarray::f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как правильно передать? гуглил, но ничего полезного не нашел, как только не пробовал

Comment: вам нужно указать в сигнатуре метода функциональный интерфейс, вы же указываете Operarray. Замените на Callable и вызывайте в методе соответствующе.

Comment: private static void func(Callable f1) {f1();} если я правильно понял то так?

Comment: а как правильно тогда в func передать метод?

Comment: Вызывать соответствующе - это `f1.call();`

Comment: Ещё не придумали как в жаве передавать методы.  
Можно только передать только объект целиком и уже у переданного объекта вызывать нужный метод.  
В java 8 в некоторых случаях можно упростить задачу, используя лямбды.  
Выглядит так, как будто действительно передаёшь что-то похожее на метод.

Comment: @Sergey строго говоря MethodHandle есть

Comment: @etki разве methodHanler-у не требуется объект, у которого будет вызываться метод?

Comment: @Sergey да, чет думал что он при создании биндится. Но статику можно и так вызывать )

Comment: @etki Но ведь статика она же тоже не сама по себе, а находится внутри какого-то класса. Значит должна быть привязка к объекту класса Class. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените тип параметра на [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

```
class Operarray {
    public static void f() {
        System.out.println("123");
    }

    private static void func(Runnable f1) {
        f1.run();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func(Operarray::f);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/rtjD0n

Comment: а если метод с аргументами? например public static void f(a,b) {return a + b;}

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). Скажем, если метод принимает `int` и `double` и возвращает `String`, то подойдёт `BiFunction<Integer, Double, String>`. Если метод принимает больше двух параметров, то можно написать свой функциональный интерфейс.

Comment: мой метод выглядит так public static long som(long a, long b) {return a + b; } а вызов Operarray.operArray(Operarray::som, a, a[0]) где a-массив

Comment: И `BiFunction` не подходит? http://ideone.com/SdNb9P

Comment: я немного не пойму как это реализовать

Comment: Ну, я же скинул ссылку на ideone (вот она http://ideone.com/SdNb9P).

Comment: спасибо, не заметил ссылку

Comment: после js где это реализовано по другому не привычно юзать такой подход

Comment: да, js достаточно сильно отличается

Comment: @diraria Вопрос на засыпку. А если метод с тремя аргументами? Например public static void f(a,b,c) { a + b + c;} :)

Comment: @Sergey, надо будет написать свой функциональный интерфейс :) Примерно такой: http://ideone.com/jWRpFU

Answer (score 4):

Механизм лямбд, пришедший в восьмой джаве, проще всего рассматривать как синтаксический сахар (на самом деле под капотом все немного сложней). Он позволяет заменить громоздкие объявления анонимных классов:

```
public static void invoke(Callable callable) {
    callable.call();
}

public static void doWork() {
    invoke(new Callable() {
        database.truncate();
    });
}
```

На короткие ссылки на методы:

```
public static void doWork() {
    invoke(database::truncate);
}
```

При этом внутри JVM будет создан экземпляр интерфейса `Callable` (точнее, в этом месте компилятором будет внедрен соответствующий код создания), который выполнит `database.truncate()` при вызове, и который будет передан в указанный метод - таким образом **принимающий метод не работает с "методом другого класса", он работает с конкретным объектом**. Вся магия сосредоточена именно в создании новой имплементации интерфейса на лету в том месте, где вы ссылаетесь на метод, вся остальная работа остается такой же, как и была, и специальных типов не появляется.

Забегая немного вперед - Java поддерживает такую автоматическую конвертацию для всех функциональных интерфейсов. Под функциональным интерфейсом, в свою очередь, подразумевает интерфейс, содержащий ровно один метод для реализации - другими словами, интерфейс, который можно было бы реализовать с помощью функции, если бы они существовали в Java.