# как передать указатель на функцию как аргумент java android

Tags: java, android

есть функция в android java показывающая интерактивное диалоговое окно,
очень хочется передать ей через аргумент функции которые будут вызываться при нажатии
на кнопки Yes, No, Dismiss, чтобы сделать ее универсальной а не переписывать каждый раз.
Извините,в java новичок, мыслю категориями Си.Подскажите как это сделать

```
public int DialogMakeChose(String txtMsg1, String txtMsg2, ***p* funcYes***) {


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View dialog1View = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog1, null);
    TextView textViewDlg1 = dialog1View.findViewById(R.id.textViewD1);
    TextView textViewDlg2 = dialog1View.findViewById(R.id.textViewD2);
    textViewDlg1.setText(txtMsg1);
    textViewDlg2.setText(txtMsg2);
    builder.setView(dialog1View);
    //builder.setTitle(Title)
            //.setMessage(txtMsg)
            //                       .setMessage("Are you sure, you want to continue ?")
            //.setCancelable(false)
    builder .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ***funcYes****
                    chose = 1;
                    setMinSizePicture();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    chose = 0;
                }
            })
            .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {showSizePicture(); }
             });
             //       setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
             //   @Override
             //   public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {  showSizePicture();    }

    //Creating dialog box
    AlertDialog dialog  = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return chose;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить создать функцию Yes в твоем главном классе активности public class *** extends AppCompatActivity, тогда ты сможешь обратиться к ней по названию из любого места в классе. Должно сработать в твоем случае, потому что лично я как такой же новичок не сталкивался с тем, что я вынужден выходить за пределы главного класса.

Comment: Спасибо! Это уже реализовано ( см. код Yts = setMinSizePicture(); ). Вопрос как менять саму Yes )

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся! Нашел ответ на этом сайте:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/680707/433160
реально работает! Упрощает код и делает его более читабельным)

```
class Operarray {
    public static void f() {
        System.out.println("123");
    }

    private static void func(Runnable f1) {
        f1.run();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func(Operarray::f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я у себя сделал так:

```
private void createTwoButtonsAlertDialog(String title, String content, String base) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(content);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.NO,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (base.equals("fuel") | (base.equals("all"))) {
                          // 1 вариант
                    }
                    if (base.equals("stat") | (base.equals("all"))) {
                          // 2 вариант
                    }
                    if (base.equals("auto") | (base.equals("all"))) {
                          // 3 вариант
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```

Вызов такой:

```
createTwoButtonsAlertDialog("ServiceNote", "Удалить базу?", "stat");
```

Вы можете в качестве аргумента передать что угодно

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже пришел к такому решению  через switch. Но как то неудобно каждый раз влезать и править саму функцию и помнить все условия. Надеюсь найти более изящное решение.

Comment: В любом случае придётся его использовать

Comment: не придется! ) Смотрите мой ответ